# Need to remove numbers at end of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working in Ruby and I need a regex to detect where that last whitespace is return everything before the whitespace. The last part of the string is a number if that helps.

Example string:

```
a = "Dallas Cowboys 34"
```

Here is the best regex I could come up with so far:

```
irb(main):090:0> a[/\D*/]
=> "Dallas Cowboys "
```

any idea of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be using [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html) to do this.

```
"Dallas Cowboys 34".gsub(/ *\d+$/, '')
#=> "Dallas Cowboys"
```

Or you could do this without using a regular expression..

```
"Dallas Cowboys 34".split[0...-1].join ' ' 
#=> "Dallas Cowboys"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just looking for everything up to the last whitespace, you don't actually need a regex. You can use [String#rpartition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition) instead:

```
a.rpartition(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+$
```

and replace it with nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
a.rpartition(/\D/)[0]
```

This way you're always gonna get everything before the space before the last numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
r = /.*?(?=\s+\S*$)/ 

"Dallas Cowpokes   34"[r] #=> "Dallas Cowpokes"
"Dallas Cowpokes 34  "[r] #=> "Dallas Cowpokes 34"
```

- `?` following `.*` makes the latter "non-greedy".
- `(?=...)` is a (zero-width) positive lookahead, meaning the match must be immediately followed by a substring that matches `/\s+\S*$/`; that is, one or more whitespace characters followed by zero or more non-whitespace characters, followed by the end of the line.
- If the regex were not made non-greedy, `.*` would gobble up all but the last whitespace character:

  `"Dallas Cowpokes   34"[/.*(?=\s+\S*$)/] #=> "Dallas Cowpokes  "`